# DappHub Multiply Function

Tags: ether, erc-20, security

Could someone explain the use of performing a multiplication such as this? **I mean the logic is fine, but what is the importance from a security point of view?**

```
function mul(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x, "ds-math-mul-overflow");
    }
```

This is from the dapphub library.
I have included the link herewith: 
https://github.com/dapphub/ds-math/blob/master/src/math.sol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From security point of view, it is ensuring that after multiplication, returned value is not getting overflowed.

Suppose we have a 8-bit unsigned integer which store value from 0 to 255. So the multiplication of `130*2` will return 260 and when it will be time to store it in variable it will be get overflowed and will store the value `5`. So this `require` in question checks that if we perform the reverse operation, we should get the initial value which will not be possible in overflow bug.

`y == 0` will be an exception in the detection of above case so code is considering it separately.

For more: https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/#integer-overflow-and-underflow

Answer (score 0):

```
function sub(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require((z = x - y) <= x, "ds-math-sub-underflow");
    }
```

checks `x-y <= x` and if condition(`x-y <= x`) is true, return `z(x-y)`

in the case `x-y > x` , print log "ds-math-sub-underflow" and throws

Comment: I understand the logic. Logic is not a problem. I have mentioned it in my question. What I need to understand is why do we need to do this? Why not plain x*y? What are the implications from a security point of view?

Comment: some accident[https://medium.com/smartmesh/smartmesh-announcement-on-ethereum-smart-contract-overflow-vulnerability-f1ded8777720] happens

Comment: Could not access the link. Says 404

Comment: [link again](https://medium.com/smartmesh/smartmesh-announcement-on-ethereum-smart-contract-overflow-vulnerability-f1ded8777720)